# Flushright, Allignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

[image]

I want to align text as in the picture above. Starting from supervisor till Patiala.
I used flushright but it aligned the text from the right hand side as in the picture below. How can I correct this?

[image]

Comment: I think you are simply looking for `\raggedright` or `\begin{flushleft} stuff \end{flushleft}`.

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved with a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{CERTIFICATE}
\end{center}

This is to certify that...

\begin{flushright}
\textbf{
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    SUPERVISOR\\
    \\
    Dr./Er. XXX\\
    Professor/Assistant Professor,\\
    Department of Computer Engineering,\\
    Punjabi University,\\
    Patiala 
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```